# Creating a thread to a class object

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I have the class object `Chat *p`, and I'm looking to run the method `Foo(int num)` on it (usually running by `p -> Foo(3)` for example).
I've written this code :

```
    std::thread F(&Chat::Foo, 4);
```

though, it does not compile to me, and I also see theres an error, since I was not able to put `p -> Foo` into it (instead of `&Chat::Foo`...)

How can I run this code correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can make your Foo method as static, make it static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from how object methods actually work. When you call `p->foo(3)` what the compiler translates it to, roughly speaking, is `Chat::foo(p, 3)`. `P` is always passed as a hidden parameter in any call to a function. C++ doesn't show you this and you can't actually call `Chat::foo(p, 3)`, this just isn't allowed, but it roughly how things work in reality.

The variable `this` that is available in any member function is just the address that is passed in as the hidden first parameter and any member variables that you access in the function reference the hidden first parameter. So... what you need to do in order to call any member function as the starting point to a thread, is pass the pointer to the object as it's first parameter. `std::thread F(&Chat::Foo, p, 4);` will, I believe, start the thread properly.